# Generar Json en PHP con datos de mysql

Tags: php, mysql, json

Necesito crear un json con la siguiente estructura(foto1), ejemplo
1115 son la unión de los IDS región, provincia y ciudad.
ejem:

```
  $idRegion = 1;
  $idProvincia = 1;
  $idCiudad = 1;
  $ids = $idRegion.''.$idProvincia.''.idCiudad;
```

y donde el siguiente dato es el tipo de bencina

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
lo intente de esta manera

```
   $getAll = $db->query("SELECT regiones.id_region,regiones.nombre_region,
        provincias.id_provincia,provincias.nombre_provincia,
        ciudades.id_ciudad,ciudades.nombre_ciudad,
        bencina.id_bencinera,bencina.nombre_bencinera,bencina.calle_bencinera,bencina.precio_bencina,bencina.fecha_publicacion,
        tipobencinas.id_tipo_bencina,tipobencinas.nombre_tipo_bencina 
        FROM regiones,provincias,ciudades,bencina,tipobencinas 
        WHERE regiones.id_region = bencina.id_region AND provincias.id_provincia = bencina.id_provincia AND ciudades.id_ciudad = bencina.id_ciudad AND tipobencinas.id_tipo_bencina = bencina.id_tipo_bencina ORDER BY id_ciudad ASC");

        while($a = $db->recorrer($getAll)){



            $ben = array();
            $ids = array();
            $ids = $a['id_region'].''.$a['id_provincia'].''.$a['id_ciudad'];


            $ben[$ids] = array(
                'idRegion' => $a['id_region'],
                'nombreRegion' => $a['nombre_region'],
                'idProvincia'=> $a['id_provincia'],
                'nombreProvincia' => $a['nombre_provincia'],
                'idCiudad' => $a['id_ciudad'],
                'nombreCiudad' => $a['nombre_ciudad'],
                'idbencinera' => $a['id_bencinera'],
                'nombreBencinera' => $a['nombre_bencinera'],
                'calleBencinera' => $a['calle_bencinera'],
                'precioBencina' => $a['precio_bencina'],
                'fechaPublicacion'=> $a['fecha_publicacion'],
                'idTipoBencina' => $a['id_tipo_bencina'],
                'nombreTipoBencina' => $a['nombre_tipo_bencina']
            );

            array_push($bencina['bencina'],$ben);

        }

    }else{    

    }

    $salidaJson = array( "bencina" => $bencina,
                "tiposBencinas" => $tiposBencinas);

    echo json_encode($salidaJson);
```

pero no obtuve resultados esperados, desde ya agradezco cualquier orientación.

adjunto base de datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: pon el resultado que obtuviste con lo que intentaste para una mejor visualización

Comment: La idea es que tu array **debe tener la misma estructura que el JSON que deseas.** Por tanto el array debe tener una clave `111`, y dentro de esa clave otros sub-arrays con claves 1, 2... Puedes organizar la consulta para que arroje todos o parte de los datos así o armarlo por partes, ya eso lo decides tú. El array debe quedar así más o menos: `$arr=array(111=>array(1=>array("Bencina_mas_barata"=>1, "fecha"=>"...", "fecha_publicacion"=>"..."), 2=>array("clave"=>"valor")));`

Comment: Haz una prueba con ese mismo array:  `echo json_encode($arr);`  Te saldrá algo así: `{"111":{"1":{"Bencina_mas_barata":1,"fecha":"...","fecha_publicacion":"..."},"2":{"clave":"valor"}}}` Puedes organizar la misma consulta con `CONCAT` para que te traiga un JSON completo o usar una función de MySQL que te crea un JSON (disponible a partir de versiones modernas, no recuerdo ahora si a partir de la v. 8).